# Convert non-spatial Oracle table to spatial Oracle table in a different database

Tags: oracle-dbms, ogr2ogr, oracle-spatial

I'm trying to use ogr2ogr to convert data from a non-spatial table (has X & Y values) in an Oracle database (1) to a spatial format in a different Oracle database (2).  This will be scheduled to run daily to overwrite the table in Oracle database (2) each time.

I have it working using a ogr2ogr's Virtual File Format, with the file `Oracle.vrt` which is like:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTLayer name="TEST_X_Y">
    <SrcDataSource>OCI:userid_1/password_1@database_instance_1:TEST_X_Y</SrcDataSource>
    <SrcLayer>TEST_X_Y</SrcLayer>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>EPSG:27700</LayerSRS>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="X_TEXT" y="Y_TEXT"/>
  </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Then using the following ogr2ogr command:

```
ogr2ogr -update -overwrite -f OCI OCI:userid_2/password_2@database_instance_2:TEST_OGR_IN Oracle.vrt TEST_X_Y -lco OVERWRITE=YES -lco SRID=27700 -nln TEST_OGR_IN
```

Now this works and creates the spatial table in the Oracle database (2) fine, but when I run the ogr2ogr command a second time I get an error like:

```
ERROR 1: ORA-00001: unique constraint (MDSYS.UNIQUE_LAYERS) violated
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_TRIG_INS1", line 43
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_TRIG_INS1' in
  INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA VALUES ('TEST_X_Y',
...
```

The table (`TEST_OGR_IN`) still gets overwritten/updated in the Oracle database (2) but the problem appears to be that ogr2ogr has inserted values into the `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` table on the Oracle database (1) for the non-spatial table (`TEST_X_Y`) and is violating an index/constraint?

Although the process works, I'd like to understand why the error is happening and how I can avoid it.

Comment: I have the same problem (GDAL 1.10.0).
It seems very unreasonable to me for ogr2ogr to add rows to USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA when copying data FROM Oracle.
Interestingly the problem does not exist when the name of the source table/view is shorter than 10 characters.
It must be a bug in GDAL for sure.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Perhaps running the command with --debug on could give some information about what GDAL is trying to do.

Comment: Do you have a DBLink between these two databases?  If so it may be easier to do this within the database with a materialized view/snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same (or similar) issue with simply reading from a database. I noticed as well that a non-spatial table was being added to the SDO_GEOM_METADATA table. To resolve it, I removed the table name from the OCI connection string. Since I had the two tables (joining a non-spatial to the spatial for the query) in the SQL, it still worked and I no longer had the trigger going off. I should note I'm running from the C++ GDAL interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ogr so am just approaching this from my (limited) Oracle Spatial perspective.

It looks like you have a issue with a built in trigger - `MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_TRIG_INS1`. For me that trigger looks like:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER SDO_GEOR_TRIG_INS1
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON user_sdo_geor_sysdata
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SDO_GEOR_INT.insertUserSysEntry(user, :new.table_name, :new.column_name,
      :new.metadata_column_name, :new.rdt_table_name, :new.raster_id,
      :new.other_table_names);
END;
```

There's a post about ORA-04088 here that may help resolve it - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_04088_error_during_execution_of_trigger_string_string.htm

You could try disabling the trigger possibly for this insert then re-enabling it afterward.

You can also manually edit USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA after the fact to remove the undesired entry.

My own guess would be that your OGR isn't providing sufficient information about the non-spatial data for the trigger to be able to fill the new entry properly.

(StackOverFlow has a lot of Oracle experts if this rather shaky answer doesn't help, its where I ask my Oracle questions)